# How to get text including links (just the text part) from DOM?

Tags: jquery

By using jQuery I have to extract texts and possible links from DOM.

For example:

```
This is a the first paragraph with a given link. More text.

This is a second paragraph with another link and text.
```

The result process should be an array like the following:

aTexts = [ "This is a the first paragraph with a given link. More text.",
"This is a second paragraph with another link and text."];

I've started with the next code:

```
$('#toParse').contents().filter(function() { 
  if ( this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE ) {
    that.aTexts.push(this.nodeValue);
  }
})
```

How can I include link texts as part of texts in which links are included?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = $('p').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/XxqMY/) <-- look at the console...